# Tests should be wrapped into act(...)?

Tags: react-admin

The docs say React-admin encourages e2e instead of unit tests, and looking at the spec  files I'm not seeing the usual stubbing and mocking to isolate the code-under-test.   Further, when I try to test my own `<List />` with a data grid, based on the `List.spec.js`, I get the error below.  Is this an example of something that should only get covered by e2es, or can I isolate it, and if so how?

*BTW: Wrapping it in an `act()` still produces the same error.*

```
  When testing, code that causes React state updates 
should be wrapped into act(...):

  act(() => {
    /* fire events that update state */
  });
  /* assert on the output */

  This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user 
  would see in the browser.
  Learn more at fb.me/react-wrap-tests-with-act
      in List (at mm-services.tsx:7)
      in ServiceList (at mm-services.test.tsx:54)
      in ThemeProvider (at mm-services.test.tsx:53)
      in Router (created by TestContext)
      in Provider (created by TestContext)
      in TestContext
```

Comment: I have the same error, did you ever figure it out?